# Issue in converting float to int while calculating median of two sorted array

Tags: python, arrays, floating-point, integer, median

Code from lines 15 to 17 is returning 3.0 in the case where `e` is 2 and `q` is 4, but I want 3 instead.

```python
for i in array2:
        array1.append(i)
        arr=array1
        arr.sort()
        n = len(arr)
        if n % 2 == 0:
            z = n // 2
            e = int(arr[z])
            q = int(arr[z - 1])
            if(e+q%2==0):
                ans=int((e + q) // 2) #i did int() and also used // while dividing
                return ans #returnin 3.0 instead of 3
            else:
                ans = (e + q) / 2
                return ans
        else:
            z = n // 2
            ans = arr[z]
            return ans
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a order of precedence issue:

```
e+q%2==0
```

is being evaluated as:

```
e+(q%2)==0
```

which will never be true if e is non-zero. So, you're falling through to the `else` clause and performing float division.
You'll want to use:

```
(e+q) % 2 == 0
```